# RegEx: Repeat sub expression of regex matching html tag

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I am trying to replace all words that match a particular pattern in text using Python 2.7

Some input strings:

```
<p style="color: aaaaaa;">Stack Overflow:</p>
<P style="color: aaaaaa;">Stack Overflow: </P>
```

I want to replace text in all `<p>` or `<P>` tags which has words with first uppercase letter and ends with colon (:)

My regex so far:

```
re = '<[pP] .*>((?:(?:[A-Z][^\s:]*)[\s:])*)</[pP]>'
re.sub(re, '# \1', input)
```

This is not working. What am I missing?

Comment: Why not use an HTML parser, it's more suitable for the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your engine supports `\K`, use regex pattern `<[pP]\b[^>]*>\K\s*[A-Z][^<]*:\s*(?=<\/[pP]>)`

Otherwise go with:

```
re.sub(r'(<[pP]\b[^>]*>)\s*([A-Z][^<]*:)\s*(?=<\/[pP]>)', r'\1# \2', input)
```

See demo [**here**](http://ideone.com/SayZSE).

Comment: there is no capturing group?

Comment: I must capture inner text because then I am going to prepend # to it

Comment: @UmairAshraf - `re.sub` replaces match, not groups, so it is possible without groups...

Comment: @UmairAshraf - You should clarity your question and show desired output.

Comment: Nice it works, thanks. Your regex seems more or less like my regex. Can you tell me what was being escaped with my regex?

Comment: @UmairAshraf - There are several errors in your regex. You cannot expect to learn regex here :)

Answer (score 1):

The following regex will capture the inner text of the `<P>` tags. It ensures that each word starts with a capital letter.

```
(<[Pp][^>]*>)\s*(([A-Z]\S*\s*)*)(<\/[Pp]>)
```

**Python:**

```
re.sub('(<[Pp][^>]*>)\s*(([A-Z]\S*\s*)*)(<\/[Pp]>)', '#\\2', input)
```

**Output:**

```
#Stack Overflow:
#Stack Overflow:
```

Comment: Updated. Now inner text is in group 2, closing tag is group 3.

Comment: It will work but first letter of every word must be uppercase :)

Comment: Changed it to require each word to start with a capital but I see Omega's answer is working fine for you now.